# Python Yahoo Data Feed

Tags: python

The code below is receiving data from Quandl and is working fine. My problem is I do not know how to retrieve data from yahoo instead of Quandl. Is there someone who can tell me how can I use the same code with Yahoo data feed. It can be any instrument. The best will be the SPY etf.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sp500_daily = quandl.get("CHRIS/CME_ES1",
                     start_date="2000-1-1",
                     end_date="2017-4-15")
sp500_daily.columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close',
                 'Change', 'Settle', 'Volume',
                 'Open Interest']

multiplier = 50

# close[0] <= close[9] &&
# low[0] <= low[1] &&
# low[3] <= high[6] &&
# volume[0] <= volume[1]
 signal = ((sp500_daily.Close <= sp500_daily.shift(9).Close) &
      (sp500_daily.Low <= sp500_daily.shift(1).Low) &
      (sp500_daily.shift(3).Low <= sp500_daily.shift(6).High) &
      (sp500_daily.Volume <= sp500_daily.shift(1).Volume))
# hold time 1 day
profits = (signal * multiplier * (sp500_daily.shift(-1).Close - 
sp500_daily.Close))
returns = (signal * (-1 + sp500_daily.shift(-1).Close / sp500_daily.Close))

profits.cumsum().plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas_datareader (formerly pandas.io).

For example:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime


start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()

f = web.DataReader("^GSPC", 'yahoo', start, end)

print (f.tail())
```

Check their site for more:
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
The pandas_datareader also supports google finance, FRED and a few more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could use the yahoo finance api: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

I have not personally used it, but the link above seems to provide good examples of its use.